# How do I select nth-of-type selector that is set to display:none, to change it to display:block when a btn is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div of imgs that I'm using nth-of-type to select some of the imgs then using display:none but what I'm looking for is when a link(btn) is clicked, it shows (display:block) the imgs that were hidden.

```
<div class="item prop-item">
    <a href="<?= $permalink ?>">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(<?= $thumbnail ?>);"></div>
        <div class="title title-prop"><?= $title ?></div>
        <div class="blurb blurb-prop"><?= $blurb ?></div>
    </a>
</div>

div.prop-item:nth-of-type(-n + 2) {
    display: none;
}

<a href="#" class="link">
    <div id="showImgs" class="link-text">load More</div>
</a>

propBtn = document.getElementById("showImgs");
propItem = document.getElementsByClassName("prop-item");
propItem.onclick = function(){
    if("display" === "none"){
        propItem.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have, for example, five elements and every odd element is display none, then you can have class d-block, which will be this:

```
.d-block{
  display:block;
}
```

Then you will add class to every odd element, class with name, for example, element-odd, with propery: display:none.

```
.elements-odd{
  display:none;
}
```

Then you will do this:

```
var oddElements = document.getElementsByClassName('elements-odd');
for(var i = 0; i < oddElements.length; i++){
  oddElements[i].classList.add('d-block');
}
```

Comment: I see. What if instead of odd elements it's the last 2 elements using :nth-of-type(-n + 2)?

Comment: With pure CSS3 that is posible with nth-last-of-type(-n+2).

Comment: How would I use that to display those imgs when a btn is clicked in js?

Comment: You can try something like this: document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-last-of-type(-n+2)');